# Memoir citation in margin

Tags: biblatex, memoir, marginpar

I am trying to add more information about the citations in the margins of the page. I am using the `memoir` document class. Essentially, I do not want to change anything about the `cite` command, I just want to add information in the margin.

What I have so far is this:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,twoside,openany]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\setmarginnotes{0.15in}{1.35in}{\baselineskip}
\setulmarginsandblock{1in}{1in}{*}
\setlrmarginsandblock{2.5in}{1.0in}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout
\reversemarginpar

\usepackage[hyperref=true,style=numeric-comp,
            giveninits=true,backref,autocite=superscript,
            sorting=none]{biblatex}

\newbibmacro{sidecite}{%
  \scriptsize%
  \printfield{labelnumber}.
  \printnames{labelname}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
  \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}%
  \setunit{\addperiod\space}%
  \printfield{year}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\mcite}
  {}
  {\printtext[bibhyperref]{\textsuperscript{\printfield{labelnumber}}}%
    \marginpar{\usebibmacro{sidecite}}%
   }
  {}
  {}

% bib-file
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Knu86,
  author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
  year = {1986},
  title = {The \TeX book},
}
@BOOK{KandR,
  AUTHOR    = {Kernighan, Brian W. and Ritchie, Dennis M.},
  TITLE     = {{The C Programming Language Second Edition}},
  PUBLISHER = {Prentice-Hall, Inc.},
  YEAR      = {1988},
}
@book{Gladwell2005,
    author = {Gladwell, Malcolm},
    address = {New York, NY},
    publisher = {Back Bay Books},
    title = {Blink: The Power of Thinking Without Thinking},
    year = {2005},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1] All hail Knuth.\mcite{Knu86}

\lipsum[2-3]
\TeX is hard\mcite{KandR,Gladwell2005}, but not impossible.

It should look like this: \TeX is hard\autocite{KandR,Gladwell2005}, but not impossible. Or perhaps even this\autocite{Knu86,KandR,Gladwell2005}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

There are several problems here:

1) The superscript in the `mcite` command does not act as nice as the `autocite` command, in that it has problems figuring out its proper place when there is punctuation.

2) Citations are no longer being combined nicely, i.e. instead of "2,3", now it says "23". In the same way, citation numbers should be combined to "1-3".

3) The `mcite` command does not work in captions.

Any idea how to fix any of these issues?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since it is quite tricky to create a `\marginpar` from within a superscript this approach uses the two-pass structure employed by `\textcite`.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,twoside,openany]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setmarginnotes{0.15in}{1.35in}{\baselineskip}
\setulmarginsandblock{1in}{1in}{*}
\setlrmarginsandblock{2.5in}{1.0in}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout
\reversemarginpar

\usepackage[style=numeric-comp,
            giveninits=true, backref, autocite=superscript,
            sorting=none, labeldateparts]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{sidecite}{\marginpar{\scriptsize#1}}
\newbibmacro{sidecite}{%
  \printtext[sidecite]{%
    \printfield{labelprefix}%
    \printfield{labelnumber}%
    \setunit{\addperiod\space}%
    \printnames{labelname}%
    \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
    \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}%
    \setunit{\addperiod\space}%
    \printlabeldate}%
  \setunit{}}

\makeatletter
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cbx@superpluscite}[\mkbibsuperscript]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \let\multicitedelim=\supercitedelim
   \iffieldundef{prenote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
   \iffieldundef{postnote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\superpluscite}[\cbx@superpluscite@init\cbx@superpluscite]
  {\gdef\cbx@savedkeys{}%
   \citetrackerfalse%
   \pagetrackerfalse%
   \DeferNextCitekeyHook%
   \usebibmacro{cite:init}}
  {\xappto\cbx@savedkeys{\thefield{entrykey},}%
   \usebibmacro{sidecite}}
  {}
  {\protected@xappto\cbx@savedcites{{\cbx@savedkeys}}}

\newrobustcmd{\cbx@superpluscite@init}[2]{%
  \def\cbx@savedcites{#1}#2\cbx@savedcites\empty}

\DeclareCitePunctuationPosition{\superpluscite}{f}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1] All hail Knuth.\superpluscite{knuth:ct:a}

\lipsum[2-3]
\TeX is hard\superpluscite{knuth:ct:a,sigfridsson}, but not impossible.

It should look like this: \TeX is hard\autocite{knuth:ct:a,sigfridsson}, but not impossible. Or perhaps even this\autocite{knuth:ct:a,sigfridsson,worman}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

*edit* Updated for version 3.12 (2018-10-30) of `biblatex`. Please look at the edit history if you are using an older version.

Comment: Awesome! One minor thing though: As you can see on the second line from the bottom, "Tex is hard..." the citations still come before the comma. Do you know of any way to ensure that the citations always come after the comma (like the `autocite` command does, which is shown on the last line)?

Comment: @maero21 `\autocite` is the only cite command that supports this. I have added a hack to allow `\superpluscite` to do the same.

Comment: This approach seems to have stopped working in TeX Live 2020 with a whole bunch of `control sequence undefined` for `\iffieldundef`, `\BibliographyWarning`, and `LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.` at the call to the first `iffieldundef`. Any ideas on how to make this answer work with the latest LaTeX distribution?

Comment: @maero21 Check out the edit, please.

Comment: Thanks so much!